# ARIA: Treat HTML element as a whole

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria, screen-readers

Is there any way to tell an assistive tool to treat an element (e.g: `<div>`) as a whole, and not split it in child elements?

## First example

Using iOS VoiceOver and a  with a  field on it, it gets splitted into two  different elements:

[image: Screen shot of a control showing focus on just one part of the text.]

## Second example

This elements are splitted in two parts, where the best solution would be read "122 points" and "First position":

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="stat lg col-xs-6">
        <span>122</span>
        <i class="icon icon-prize" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <h5>Points</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="stat lg col-xs-6">
        <span>1º</span>
        <i class="icon icon-prize" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <h5>Position</h5>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Screen shot of a control showing focus on just one part of the text.]

Comment: Your question appears to be missing some detail. Can you paste the HTML that you used for the screen cap? Also, note that screen readers intentionally break long chunks of text based on user settings.

Comment: I've included the HTML. Screen readers intentionally break long chunks of text, but wouldn't it be better if we can specify how are they read? `aria-label` it's useful, but for cases like this produces a lot of redundacy code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that using `role="button"` the element is treated as a group and its innerText property is read, but announced as a button.

Answer (score 1):

VoiceOver on iOS does indeed sometimes split a sentence, although your example code actually works fine.  I used your code as the first line in the screen shots below and then copied the text without the `<a>` tag as the second line.  The second line gets broken up by VoiceOver but the `<a>` tag does not.

```
<span class="label info">
   <a href="/round/next">
      Next round starts <strong>in 3 days</strong>
   </a>
</span>
<br>
Next round starts <strong>in 3 days</strong>
```

(**Note:** I have the enhanced outline turned on for VoiceOver so the black outline is probably thicker than what you're used to seeing.)

[image]

Comment: What about more complex situations? I've updated the example

Comment: With your updated example, my reply no longer matches your original screen shots so it looks a little confusing.  Can you include your previous example as well as the new example?  For the new sample, what I typically do is put an aria-label on the main container and then set aria-hidden=true on the subcomponents.  There isn't a need for assistive technology to get to the individual pieces if they don't add more information.  With my eyes, I see your "122 points" and the trophy icon as one thing, not as three separate things so it should be the same experience for screen readers.

Comment: That's the point, but addng an `aria-label` for every component like this is a lot of work, has bad performance (this is an Angular application, creating extra attributes and bindings is costly) and makes the app more difficult to translate and localize

Comment: Not sure I follow.  I thought the point of your question was how to group items together, and that's what I answered.  Are you asking about angular performance issues now?  I've never worked with angular.  Setting ARIA attributes does not cause bad performance.

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is a way to indicate VoiceOver to read the whole element content (DOM innerText property) instead of splitting it into several pieces